# How to submit a sequence of changesets into Review Board (Mercurial)?

Tags: mercurial, changeset, review-board

I want to submit a sequence of changesets as one changeset (patch) into [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/). How to do that?

Comment: Are you talking about [this Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical term for combining multiple patches into one is "folding".  If you want to truly fold a series of commits into one (changing history), then the [HistEdit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension provides a way as do [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension).

If you're just interested in generating a patch, then you have a few options. You can use `hg export` (but this will not fold the patches together, but rather dumps a series of patches to console) or you can use `hg diff` to generate a diff. More precisely,

```
hg diff -r start:end > summary.patch
```

will generate a single diff for all the changes in the range `start` to `end`. You can replace `end` with `tip` to get all changes starting with `start`. This should even work if there are merge changesets in between. (`hg export` produces odd output if there are merge changesets in there.)

Comment: More generally the act of replacing multiple commits with less is known as "Squashing commits".  histEdit just happens to call them folding etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that since you need to submit a sequence of changes in as a single item for review you should diff your final result with either the point that you started making changes or with the latest version of the code - creating a patch.  Then attach the patch, details of the version that you diffed with, etc., to the Request for Review form.